# Accomplishing in Java the same result with Destructors in C++

Tags: java, c++, oop, encoding, static

If I have this class (C++):

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship() {
        std::cout << "New ship created\n";
        ++shipCount;
    }
    ~Ship() {
        std::cout << "Ship destroyed!\n";
        --shipCount;
    }

private:
    static unsigned int shipCount = 0;
}
```

How can I achive the same result in Java?
Also, I'm told that I shouldn't override the `finalize()` method in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model it on a ShipFleet class that has list of ships. Then a ship class with details about the ship. In the Fleet class I would then have methods `join()` and `leave()`. Or you could also have in the ship class an atrribute to the ShipFleet that the ship belongs to, and when the ship is "destroyed" you ask the shipfleet it belonged to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, if I were to code this I would just have a list of `Ships` and a `ShipManager` class.  I wonder what other pattern exist.

Comment: It really depends then on top of other things that a ship / shipmanager would need to do as such to see if you'd model it differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sticks{
    private static int no=5;
    public void getSticks(){
        no=no-2;
    }
    synchronized public void returnSticks(){
        no=no+2;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return no;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample i have done using sticks